# My scrapy does not crawl the websites, can anyone help me?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I try to scrape the website of http://www.yhd.com and scrape the price and product ID there. This is my spider/test.py file. But it seems it downloads nothing at all. I do not know why.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from try_yhd.items import TryYhdItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "yhdspider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.yihaodian.com.yhcdn.cn"]
    start_urls = ['http://item.yhd.com/item/11271079',
              'http://item.yhd.com/item/2149386',
              ]

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/item/\d+']),'parse_torrent',follow = True),]
    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = TryYhdItem()
       # find the price and product id.
        item['price']= hxs.select("//span[@id='current_price']").extract()[0]
        item['id']= hxs.select("//p[@class='product_id']/text()").extract()[0]
        return item
```

This is the output.

```
2014-09-22 10:18:31-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2014-09-22 10:18:31-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2014-09-22 10:18:32-0500 [yhdspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://item.yhd.com  /item/11271079> (referer: None)
2014-09-22 10:18:32-0500 [yhdspider] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'item.yhd.com': <GET http://item.yhd.com/item/11271079>
2014-09-22 10:18:32-0500 [yhdspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://item.yhd.com/item/2149386> (referer: None)
2014-09-22 10:18:32-0500 [yhdspider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-09-22 10:18:32-0500 [yhdspider] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 447,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 68145,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 22, 15, 18, 32, 892277),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 2,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 22, 15, 18, 31, 211841)}
2014-09-22 10:18:32-0500 [yhdspider] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

AFTER modification, I get the following output log. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add item.yhd.com to the allowed_domains. The requests are getting filtered as being offsite by the `OffsiteMiddleware` middleware which is enabled by default.

```
'offsite/domains': 1,
'offsite/filtered': 2,
```

This middleware filters out every request whose host names aren’t in the spider’s allowed_domains attribute.

You have a couple of choices. If the spider doesn’t define an allowed_domains attribute, or the attribute is empty, the offsite middleware will allow all requests.

If the request has the dont_filter attribute set, the offsite middleware will allow the request even if its domain is not listed in allowed domains.

Comment: Thanks. But how to define an allowed_domains attribute? Or how to make the attribute empty?